# Enviar parámetro desde ajax.beginForm a ActionResult en asp.net entity framework

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, formularios, entity-framework-6

Tengo un formulario ajax.beginform el cual debe enviar un modelo y un parámetro adicional, el parámetro adicional la envío como "object routeValues", pero mi actionResult aparentemente no reconoce mi "object routeValues" que sería el siguiente:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GuardarEdicion", new { idEditarSucursal = Model.iidsucursal }, new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "div_tabla_sucursal",
                OnSuccess = "Limpiar"
            }, new { @id = "Frm_Editar" }))
            {
             // aqui dentro va el formulario, todo se envía como oSucursalCLS
             }
```

si omito el parámetro el modelo es recibido pero sigo necesitando el valor del parámetro adicional ya que es el id del registro que quiero procesar y no quiero colocarlo en un campo hidden, la acción que recibe es:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GuardarEdicion(int idEditarSucursal, SucursalCLS oSucursalCLS)
{
```

revisé que ese parámetro no estuviera null y en efecto tiene el valor del id del registro.

Comment: Indica por favor el código completo del `Ajax.BeginForm`, por si tienes mal los parámetros

Comment: Listo, actualizé la información del formulario.

Comment: En principio parece todo correcto. Sólo probaría a sustituir el método GET por POST. en la Acción `[HttpPost]` y en el AJAX `HttpMethod = "Post"` a ver si por casualidad es por eso. También sustituye `new { @id = "Frm_Editar" }` por `new { id = "FrmEditar" }`

Comment: @rafaelacosta en efecto probé eso, hice un proyecto nuevo y le dí copiar y pegar a el contenido y ahora si funciona, tanto "get" como "post", al proyecto que no me funciona le di a "recompilar proyecto" y a "reconstruir" pero no hizo cambio alguno, gracias por la sugerencia.